# Print frame around user input words or sentences

Tags: ruby, printing, frame

I am doing a coding bootcamp and into week-2 and have learnt loop, methods, a bit of classes. I have come across with this coding challenge.

I can put a frame around the sentence I put in def method. I would like to know how I can put a frame around user input words. I have tried, but am getting an error.

Ultimately, what I want to achieve is to delete `words = %w(This restaurant has an excellent menu - sushi ramen okonomiyaki.)` from def method.

Thank you!!

```
puts "Welcome to frame with words."
puts "Enter your favourite quote or sentence or any word you like"
words = gets.chomp.to_s

def my_favourite words=[]
    words = %w(This restaurant has an excellent menu - sushi ramen okonomiyaki.) 
    longest = 0
    words.each {|word| longest = word.length if longest < word.length }
    (0..longest+3).each {print "*"} 

    print "\n" 
    words.each do |word|
        print "* " 
        print word
        (0..longest-word.length).each { print " " } 
        print"*\n" 
    end
    (0..longest+3).each {print"*" } 
    return 
end
my_favourite
```

The type of output I want is below.

````
* This         *
* restaurant   *
* has          *
* an           *
* excellent    *
* menu         *
* -            *
* sushi        *
* ramen        *
* okonomiyaki. *
**************** ```
````

Comment: `gets` always returns a string ending with a newline character. You correctly have `gets.chomp` to, er, chomp off the newline character, but `chomp` also returns a string, so `.to_s` after `chomp` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

```
str = gets.chomp
  #=> "This restaurant has an excellent menu - sushi ramen."
```

then

```
words = str.split
  #=> ["This", "restaurant", "has", "an", "excellent", "menu", "-",
  #    "sushi", "ramen."]
width = words.max_by(&:size).size
  #=> 10
top_bot = '*' * (width+4)
  #=> "**************"
puts top_bot
words.each { |word| puts "* %-#{width}s *" % word }
puts top_bot
```

displays:

```
**************
* This       *
* restaurant *
* has        *
* an         *
* excellent  *
* menu       *
* -          *
* sushi      *
* ramen.     *
**************
```

`words.max_by(&:size)` is shorthand for:

```
words.max_by { |word| word.size }
  #=> "restaurant"
```

See the doc [Kernel#sprint](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for an explanation of the formatting codes in `"* %-#{width}s *" % word`. After `#{width}` is substitute out this becomes `"* %-10s *" % word`. `s` specifies that `word` is a string. `10` means it should occupy a field of width `10`. `-` means that the string should be left-adjusted in the field. The field of width `10` is preceded by `"* "` and followed by `" *"`, forming a string of width `14`.

This could instead be (equivalently) written:

```
word = "balloon"
sprintf("* %-#{width}s *", word)
  #=> "* balloon    *"
```

See also [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-split), [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) and [String#*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-2A).

Comment: Thank you very much Cary!!!! I really appreciate your explanation!!!!

Comment: Hi Cary, `"* %-#{width}s *" % word ` . I interpret this as * for left boundary before each word starts, 1) What does this  `%- ` stands for? . I understand that #{width} is string interpolation. 2) Why s is needed at the end of it but I do not see any output of s?  3) why this ` "* %-#{width}s *"` is followed by modulus % word. Thanks again. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please see my edit. `%` here does not mean modulus; it is simply part of a directive for how a string should be constructed.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I understand this expression now! `words.each { |word| puts "* %-#{width}s *" % word }` .